# Are there specific theories as to what causes cold[-water] muscle cramps?

Tags: physiology, muscles, temperature

The field of what might cause cramps is [quite contested](http://dx.doi.org/10.1136/bjsm.2008.050401) with a lot of controversy around the heat/dehydration cramps, but I find it surprising that no specific theories appear to have been proposed (or tested) while swimming, usually in cold[er] water. There's one [governmental site](https://myhealth.alberta.ca/Health/pages/conditions.aspx?hwid=za1086) that does acknowledge cold and cold water in particular as a risk factor. I for one never get cramps in a pool/water over 18 degree C, but I am quite likely to get them below that, no matter what I do in terms of stretching, drinking etc. (There's [one other site](https://aceboater.com/en/cold-water-shock-symptoms-treatment) that mentions that "muscle spasms" occur during cold-water shock, below 15 degreed C.) Am I correct that no specific theories have been proposed or tested for cold-related cramps?

---

Interestingly, the cutoff temperature I found experimentally for myself is perhaps reflected in [one article](https://www.biologyofexercise.com/images/issues/1022.pdf):

> during swimming at a water temperature of 18 [deg] C, it is noted that
>   esophageal and muscular temperatures tend to decrease, below 37 [deg] C. [3 refs cited for this fact]

So below 18 C water temperature it appears that consistent cooling of the muscles occurs. So I guess one could ask, equivalently, why muscle cooling [below 37 C] can lead to cramps.